# Personalize a title: Square + center + Huge size

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

The Doxygen don't say anything about the creation of a particular title (or even change de the size of a simple text... lame). My search are surprisingly infructuous about this simple task:

I search a way to **put a bigger title on the main page**. This title must be huge, squared and centered, here's my actual code:

```
 <div align="center">
  <table>
    <tr><td> {/Huge **Huge sized title**}
  </table>
 </div>
```

Everything work except the size, I tried it outside, font size="X" and the # don't work either.

How to use it correctly?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Where do you want to have the title (maybe an image might give some clues)? Where do you invoke the mentioned code? Any special settings in your doxygen configuration file?

Comment: Well, I used Doxywizard 1.8.15 , I guess this is the last version of Doxygen.
I thought to copy the title on the Word document as an image to make the job easier, but it's better to make an editable title.
It must be on the main page description.
In fact, the problem is we decide de pass from a word document to a doxygen document in html format, so I am beginner here, even if I already used LaTeX before, but we must keep the same main page :/

Comment: The last version of doxygen is 1.8.16 (unless you want to be on the burning edge in that case it is the master version on github), but this will probably have no effect on your problem.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't bring me much further to a proposed solution.

Comment: Bad comment, show some code please. Maybe you have to look into the doxygen.css file to enlarge some texts, but without an example it is not possible to tell what and where you want some changes.

Comment: Maybe doxygen.css around line 1822. But better through an HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET Did you look in the chapter "Customizing the output" of the documentation?